# How to convert tuple to list with float and string values

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
tuple_list =   [(['MATH120'], 3.665, 0.4737615433949868), (['GER'], 3.4566666666666666, 0.3967146329542181), (['FREE'], 3.415636363636364, 0.450256863026264), ([''], 0.041607963246554365, 0.38832820111766464)]
```

and what I want to do is convert this to:

```
result = [['MATH120', 3.665, 0.4737615433949868],['GER', 3.4566666666666666, 0.3967146329542181],['FREE', 3.415636363636364, 0.450256863026264]]
```

meaning that I want to convert it into a list of 3 pairs and delete the whole tuple if the list it has inside has **only elements that are empty** and delete also the empty strings that might exist in the tuple for example if it was like this:

```
tuple_list = [(['MATH120',''], 3.665, 0.4737615433949868), (['GER','',''], 3.4566666666666666, 0.3967146329542181), (['FREE'], 3.415636363636364, 0.450256863026264), ([''], 0.041607963246554365, 0.38832820111766464)]
```

I want it to turn to the same as previous:

```
result = [['MATH120', 3.665, 0.4737615433949868],['GER', 3.4566666666666666, 0.3967146329542181],['FREE', 3.415636363636364, 0.450256863026264]]
```

I tried doing this in order to put them just in list:

```
result= [list(map(list, l)) for l in tuple_list]
```

but I kept on getting error because of the float values:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: A string containing a space is not empty. Consider `bool(' ') == True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>If your data is always regular like that, and you only want the first element in the inner lists, then simply:</strike>

```
>>> [[x, y, z] for [x, *_], y, z in data]
[['MATH120', 3.665, 0.4737615433949868], ['GER', 3.4566666666666666, 0.3967146329542181], ['FREE', 3.415636363636364, 0.450256863026264], ['', 0.041607963246554365, 0.38832820111766464]]
```

FINAL EDIT:

Since you've clarified that they are empty strings, we can do something a little nicer:

```
>>> [ [*filter(None, lst), a, b] for lst, a, b in data if any(lst) ]
[['MATH120', 3.665, 0.4737615433949868], ['GER', 3.4566666666666666, 0.3967146329542181], ['FREE', 3.415636363636364, 0.450256863026264]]
>>>
```

Which I actually think is quite nicely declarative

Comment: That's not what OP wanted, please read the description (and the second example) carefully.

Comment: @Błotosmętek ah, I see

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for your answer! Actually I do not want it to be converted to 'FREE' because this 'FREE' is supposed to be a course. I just want that whole sublist to be deleted in the case that the only string inside that list is empty!

Comment: @piggy see, that's confusing, because that isn't what your example shows. You have spaces which aren't empty strings. Are they actually just whitespace?

Comment: You are right I'll change it now. They are empty strigs not spaces. My apologies! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @piggy cool, then I think you can use what I have in my final edit...

Comment: works great! Now to be honest I do not know which answer is better since I am new to this, between you and @Blotosmetek below but both work perfectly for my case!

Comment: @piggy they are essentially equivalent

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can I ask you something? Is there a way to keep the string which is inside a list to still be in a seperate list but inside the final list of each tuple? To be like this for example: [['MATH120'], 3.665, 0.4737615433949868]

Comment: @piggy yea, just modifying the approach above `[ [list(filter(None, lst)), a, b] for lst, a, b in data if any(lst) ]`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 2):

```
result=  [ [e for e in l if e] + list(t) for l, *t in tuple_list if any(l) ]
```

`[e in t[0] if e]` removes empty strings from a sublist; then the remaining elements of the tuple are appended; but if there are no non-empty elements in a list (`any(t[0])` is `False`) then this tuple is skipped.

Comment: I believe you have an extra parenthesis so it must be like this:     result = [[e in t[0] if e] + list(t[1:]) for t in tuple_list if any(t[0]) ]
but I get error of invalid syntax!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is because when you call `map(list, l)`, `l` refers to an inner tuple (E.G. `(['MATH120'], 3.665, 0.4737615433949868)`), and those floats cannot be converted to a list directly. I recommend doing something like the following:

```
for listIndex in range(tuple_list):
    tuple_list[listIndex] = list(tuple_list[listIndex]) # Converts inner tuples to list
    for element in inner_tuple:
        if isinstance(element, list): # checks if element inside tuple is list
            #do logic on list that you need
```

Answer (score 1):

If your first element is always a list in your tuple, just account for it in more hardcoded way. It will only work with data in same format as examples you presented, `list(tuple(list(...), ...), ...)`

```
result_list = []
for x in tuple_list:
    temp_tuple = []
    if (len(x[0]) == 1 and x[0][0] == '') or len(x[0]) == 0:
        continue

    for y in x[0]:
        if y == '':
            continue
        temp_tuple.append(y)

    for y in range(1, len(x)):
        temp_tuple.append(x[y])

    result_list.append(temp_tuple)
```

I tested and result on examples and output was like you asked.

This solution is not one-line solution like other answers. But I personally prefer to avoid one-line loops in python if I can. That makes it easier for me to read it.

Comment: Great approach! It is more easy to read I agree(since I am new to this)! But I will just choose another answer for my project in order to have it just in one line, no other reason! But yours works great as well! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just had one level too much. Use this:

```
result = [list(x) for x in tuple_list]
```

or

```
result = list(map(list, tuple_list))
```

Comment: P.s. the rest of your post seems to be irrelevant to the problem

Comment: I don't think this is the output OP wants. You might wanna check again.

Comment: @Mayank I know the end goal is different, but I'm answering the question in the title, *"How to convert tuple to list with float and string values"*, and the thing that OP tried but had difficulty with. Also when I posted the answer, the question was inconsistent - OP was talking about empty strings but some of them weren't empty, so I left that up to them. See my P.S.